# Как оформить примечание?

Tags: оформление-текста

Как правильно сформулировать и оформить примечание? Хочу пояснить, в каком смысле употребляется украинское слово "бабка" - стрекоза, т. к. из контекста не понятно. Ставлю сноску, а внизу текст: в значении "насекомое". Так можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ставите сноску*, а в нижней части страницы пишете ***Бабка (укр.) ― стрекоза.**

Comment: Но основной текст на украинском.

Comment: Тогда ― без (укр.): *Бабка ― стрекоза.